# Node v 13 : Am I getting the 'type error: jwt.sign is not a function" because I'm using ES Modules?

Tags: node.js, jwt, es6-modules

Console Error: **TypeError: jwt.sign is not a function**

Trying out the latest Node version 13 using "type": "module" in my package.json. All is going well so far until I tried to add token authentication with 'jsonwebtoken'. Not sure if it's my code or maybe a compatibility issue? Using their ES Module has some differences from those I use in React.

create new token helper function

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

export const newToken = user => {
    return jwt.sign({id: user.id}, JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: '1d'
    })
}
```

signup function

```
export const signup = async (req, res, next) => {
 // ... 
try {
    //.. create user code ..
        const user = new User({email, password})
        user.save()
        const token = newToken(user)
        return res.json({token, user})
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        res.status(500).send('Server Error')
    }
```

and everytime I hit the signup route, I get the 500 Error, and a user still gets registered to my database. Hitting a wall a bit..

Thanks and happy holidays guys!

Edit: I just changed my import/export statements to common modules, and I was able to get tokens. Still don't know how to fix this to work with ESModules, or even what the issue is

Comment: You have still this issue when you use require instead of import ?
You have installed jsonwebtoken from npm / yarn?

Comment: @Misha yea i just changed back to common modules, only changing the code for import/export, and it works as I expect! I am confused why I only had issues with jsonwebtoken using the new modules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jsonwebtoken uses default exports to expose its functions (https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/index.js).

Therefore, you can load the module using import like this:

```
import jsonwebtoken  from 'jsonwebtoken';
const token = jsonwebtoken.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, 'shhhhh');
```

Comment: No problem :) If you want to learn more about this, check out https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f