# Why Vite development mode can resolve a module but not a built product?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, vite, es6-modules

I am developing a Fastify application with Vite.
My product uses [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) package to sign and verify JWT.

While developing, I can use all `jsonwebtoken` functions with Vite's development mode. However, after I build the application, although the building process goes well, the built application collapses and produces `TypeError: jwt.sign is not a function`.

Why the development mode works well but the built product doesn't?
Is there any way to detect the error at compile time? Or is there any mistakes in my building setting?

Here is a minimum reproduction source code. https://github.com/randyumi/20240203jsonwebtoken-vite-build

- `npm run dev` -> `curl http://localhost:8080/` -> works well and returns signed JWT.
- `npm run build` -> `NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js` -> `curl http://localhost:8080/` -> not works, says `jwt.sign is not a function`

I found an issue regarding this problem https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/655

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/q/59340633/7368018

Comment: Namespace imports and default exports are a PITA and feel like anti patterns.

Answer (score 0):

`jsonwebtoken` is a CommonJS module, so **you are importing a CommonJS module into an ES Module** and should read [interoperability with CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs).

You do not encounter the error from Vite's dev server due to [dependency pre-bundling](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling) which converts all dependencies to ESM (and is actually done by esbuild).

Your specific (namespace) import syntax is importing the **Module Namespace Exotic Object**:

```js
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
```

The above import produces something like this:

```
[Module: null prototype] {
  decode: [Function (anonymous)],
  default: {
    decode: [Function (anonymous)],
    verify: [Function (anonymous)],
    sign: [Function (anonymous)],
    JsonWebTokenError: [Function: JsonWebTokenError],
    NotBeforeError: [Function: NotBeforeError],
    TokenExpiredError: [Function: TokenExpiredError]
  }
}
```

The Node.js documentation states

> When importing a CommonJS module, it can be reliably imported using the ES module default import or its corresponding sugar syntax:

So you can change from the namespace import to a named import using `default`:

```js
import { default as jwt } from 'jsonwebtoken'
```

Which can be simplified even further with the equivalent (but sweeter) syntax sugar:

```js
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
```

Which produces the module export expected:

```
{
  decode: [Function (anonymous)],
  verify: [Function (anonymous)],
  sign: [Function (anonymous)],
  JsonWebTokenError: [Function: JsonWebTokenError],
  NotBeforeError: [Function: NotBeforeError],
  TokenExpiredError: [Function: TokenExpiredError]
}
```

FWIW, had you initially tried a named import for `sign`, the Node.js runtime would have provided helpful error messaging when attempting to start the production server.

For example, this:

```js
import { sign } from 'jsonwebtoken'
```

Would have produced this error message:

```
import { sign } from "jsonwebtoken";
         ^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'sign' not found. The requested module 'jsonwebtoken' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'jsonwebtoken';
const { sign } = pkg;

    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:132:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:214:5)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12)

Node.js v20.11.0
```

Which shows yet another syntax to properly get a handle on a reference to `sign`.